# Way too many vertices when switching to edit mode

Tags: vertices, sculpting

i am trying to create a rock by sculpting an ico sphere, but even after small amounts of sculpting, when i switch to edit mode it creates around 100,000 vertices. does anyone know how to reduce the vertices without losing the shape? i dont mind starting again on the rock by the way. 
here is a screenshot (the rock is around the size of the starting cube)
[image]

Comment: It looks like you already added a decimate modifier. That's what I would recommend. You need to apply to decimate modifier if you want your vertex count to be lower in edit mode.

Comment: Two options: in edit mode select all and do "limited dissolve", or add a decimate modifier and play with the ratio values to find a number of vertices that still holds the shape. Then just "apply the modifier" to make the change permanent.

Comment: I have tried both of these methods, but cant find any way that actually decreases the vertices. here is the video i am attempting to mimic https://youtu.be/gF6qkByl-_M?t=37m28s watch from 37:28

Comment: What is the problem in following a video? He is using dyntopo (dynamic topology) in Sculpt mode which dynamically creates vertices as you draw on surface. Look how he changes detail method and details amount and draw on icosphere. Any modifier or Edit mode operation are post-editing while dyntopo will collapse or subdivide geometry on fly.

Comment: Sculpting will always yield a lot of unnecessary geometry and a lot of triangles. My advice would be to sculpt to get the shape you need and then create a lower poly mesh and use it to re-topologize (there are countless tutorials on the subject). On the lower poly mesh you can also use a normal map created from the high res mesh to create apparent detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Shrinkwrap modifier** could help you:

1. Create new object with similar shape, big enough to cover your sculpted rock
2. Subdivide it as you would like the mesh of your rock to be detailed (or use *Subdivision Surface* modifier so you can tune it later)
3. Apply *Shrinkwrap* modifier with *Target* set to your high-poly sculpted rock.

[image]

You should get low-polygon version of your high-poly sculpted model.
There are some useful options you can use for tuning the Shrinkwrap modifier so you can look at it's overview in Blender Manual.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/shrinkwrap.html

Comment: Did this method work for you? If so, please accept the answer so others can see the solution easily.

Comment: Oh, I am glad I could help you :) Enjoy Blending :)